# Snippet with ANSI terminal escape color codes in VSCODE

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, ascii, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

im trying to create a custom snippet in order to use `console.log()` and I'm using some Ascii code because I want to make the the first logged value yellow.

So my problem is that the `snippets.json` file from VSCode in not able to read `\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m`.

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to be able to read the Ascii code from the `snippets.json` file.

https://voidcanvas.com/make-console-log-output-colorful-and-stylish-in-browser-node/

```
 "Print to console": {
        "prefix": "lg",
        "body": [
             "console.log("\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m",'$1', $2);",
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `"` and `\`

```json
"Print to console": {
  "prefix": "lg",
  "body": [
       "console.log(\"\\x1b[33m%s\\x1b[0m\", '$1', $2);",
  ],
  "description": "Log output to console"
}
```